# Отправка данных на сервер из одного поля

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, post

Есть форма, где из этого поля

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fio">
```

нужно отправить отдельно имя, фамилию и отчество.
json:

```
name: 'username',
surname: 'usersurname',
lastname: 'userlastname'
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? 
С отдельными полями для имени фам понятно, можно так

```
name: $('#name').val(),
surname: $('#surname').val(),
lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
```

А вот как из одного поля отправить данные без понятия.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Правильный пример Ajax запроса для отправки формы c помощью jQuery и JavaScript](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418501/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-jquery-%d0%b8-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы можете гарантировать, что фамилия, имя и отчество введены через пробел в правильном порядке, то вам достаточно функции `split`:

```
var fio = $('#fio').val().split(' ');
var data = {
  lastname: fio[0].val(),
  name: fio[1].val(),
  surname: fio[2].val()
};
```

Если гарантировать не можете, то вы напрашиваетесь на неприятности, запрашивая у пользователя ФИО в одном поле, а храня их отдельно.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!