# Хочу передать форму с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Всем привет. Есть у меня форма, хочу передать ее с помощью ajax, т.е. без перезагрузки страницы - возможно ли это сделать?

```html
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $variable_products['available_variations'] ) ) ?>" data-quantity="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="" />
  <button type="submit" class="button add_to_cart_button"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос уже имеет ответ вот [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418501/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-%D0%B8-javascript), тоже без перезагрузки

Comment: Возможно, но детально розясни что ты хочешь передать через аякс и что получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже несколько лет как есть `FormData`, предназначенный для передачи форм через `XMLHttpRequest`, в том числе в формате `multipart/form-data`. В простейшем случае можно в него просто скормить html-элемент с формой:

```js
function send_form(form){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(form.method, form.action);
    x.onload = x.onerror = function(){alert('Отправилось')};
    x.send(new FormData(form));
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'
  onsubmit="return send_form(this);" action="//example.com/">
  <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="" />
  <button type="submit" class="button add_to_cart_button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно воспользоваться методом jQuery `serialize()`

```
<form method="POST" id="formx" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="sendData()">
... инпуты ...
</form>
```

в JS описываете функцию:

```
sendData = function() {
  var dataReq = $('form').serialize(); //здесь подставить нужный селектор
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/path/', //путь обработчика
      data: dataReq,
      success: function(dataResp) {
        $('#result').html(dataResp);
      }
    });
}
```

В PHP вы получите строку, которую сможете [распарсить](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php).