# Записать в БД несколько строк сразу

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

СУБД: MySQL 5.5, сервер: Apache 24, PHP 7, пробую сделать без фреймворков.

Добрый день, столкнулся с **такой проблемой**:

На одной странице необходимо ввести количество добавляемых записей, на другой необходимо их заполнить и на третьей вывести результат обработки этих записей: сколько добавлено, какие не добавлены и почему.

*Здесь я задаю поля для ввода*:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $id = 'id'.$i;$name = 'name'.$i;$age = 'age'.$i;$info = 'info'.$i;
    echo('
      <form action="#" method="post" id="add">
        <table>
          <tr><td>Id<td><input name=$id type="text" id=$id maxlength=3 size=5>
              <td>Name<td><input name=$name type="text" id=$name maxlength=7 size=12>
              <td>Age<td><input name=$age type="text" id=$age maxlength=3 size=5>
              <td>Info<td><input name=$info type="text" id=$info maxlength=20 size=15>
        </table>
    ');
}

echo('
  <p><input type="submit" value ="OK"></p>
  </form>
');
```

Здесь пытаюсь считать значения и передать их дальше, пробовал различными способами, остановился на этом.

Каким образом записать значения в массив *FormData* из нескольких строк? Или четыре массива для каждого поля сделать и передать их по одному?

```
$(function() {
  $("#add").submit(function() {
      var i = 0;
      var id="#id"+i;var name="#name"+i; var age="#age"+i;var info="#info"+i;
      for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
          var id='#id'+i;var name='#name'+i; var age='#age'+i;var info='#info'+i;
          formData = {
            "id":$(id).val(),
            "name":$(name).val(),
            "age":$(age).val(),
            "info":$(info).val() 
          };     
      }
      alert(formData.id1[0]);
      $.ajax({
        url:'add_res.php'
        , type:'POST'
        , data:'jsonData=' + $.toJSON(formData)
        , success: function(res) {
            alert(res);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

*Обработчик*:

```
<?php
  $data = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);
  $response = 'Получено записей '.count($data)."\n";
  foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
    $response .= 'Параметр: '.$key.'; Значение: '.$value."\n";
  }
  echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: data:'jsonData=' + $.toJSON(formData)  заменить на data: 'id='+formData.id+'&name='+formData.name+'&age='+formData.age+'&info='+formData.info

Comment: Ну или так , data:$( this ).serialize() В принципе стройн ту жe самую qury_string

Comment: А что тогда писать в обработчике? И не нужно ли указать toJSON?

Comment: В обработчике уже их можно получить следующим образом echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);
echo 'id='.$_POST['id'];
echo 'name='.$_POST['name'];
И т д
То Есть $datа = $_POST; вместо $data = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);

Comment: Для начала переделайте, чтобы в цикле у вас добавлялись только строки внутри формы, а не сами формы с одинаковыми id. Затем уже сабмит с data: $(this).serialize(), как написал товарищ выше.

Comment: Id разные добавляются, в начале цикла посмотрите

Comment: Да блин зря я не заметил ваш цикл . Так в цикле вы действительно несколько раз создаётe форму с тем же id='add', поменять id на класс и уже потом ловить event

Comment: в цикл добавил: $add = 'add'.$i;
<form action="#" method="post" class=$add> 
Я вас правильно понял?

Answer (score 2):

На первой странице составьте правильную структуру данных.
В вашем коде вы создаёте несколько форм, это неправильно. Вам нужно создать одну форму и уже к ней добавить нужные поля.

```
<form method="post" id="add" onsubmit="return false">
    <table>
        <?php for ($i = 0, $num = 4; $i < $num; $i++) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>
                <input name="id[<?php echo $i?>]" type="text" id="id-<?php echo $i?>" maxlength=3 size=5 title="">
            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>
                <input name="name[<?php echo $i?>]" type="text" id="name-<?php echo $i?>" maxlength=7 size=12 title="">
            </td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>
                <input name="age[<?php echo $i?>]" type="text" id="age-<?php echo $i?>" maxlength=3 size=5 title="">
            </td>
            <td>Info</td>
            <td><input name="info[<?php echo $i?>]" type="text" id="info-[<?php echo $i?>]" maxlength=20 size=15 title=""></td>
            <?php endfor; ?>
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="OK" id="submit"></p>
</form>

<!-- ТУТ наш результат ->
<div id="result"></div>
```

Далее наш `JS`

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'add_res.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#add").serialize(),
            success: function(res) {
                $('#result').html(res);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Примерно так, достаточно сериализовать форму с помощью `$("#add").serialize()`

Ну а обработка что-то в этом роде.

```
$response = 'Получено записей '. count($_POST['id']) . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
    // Группа
    $id = $_POST['id'][$key];
    $name = $_POST['name'][$key];
    $age = $_POST['age'][$key];
    $info = $_POST['info'][$key];

    // Далее можно и вывести как нужно
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Имена переписываете в виде [$i]name, [$i]age, etc. Итого в POST вам придут данные в виде

```
[
 0 => [name => "", age => ""],
 1 => [name => "", age => ""],
]
```

Ну и конечно это все должно быть внутри одной формы, которая будет сабмититься.

Comment: Записать имена в таком виде: <input name="[$i]id" type="text" id="[$i]id" maxlength=3 size=5>

Comment: это вопрос? id только пишите без []

Comment: <input name="[$i]id" type="text" id="id" maxlength=3 size=5> Вот так?

Comment: ну id не могут быть одинаковыми, добавляйте к ним зачение $i, хоть через дефис, хоть как, хоть вообще уберите id, у вас все равно нет лейблов для них.

Answer (score 0):

в html коде укажите имя формы `<form name="items" method="post" id="add" onsubmit="return false">`, затем 
[отправляете форму через $.ajax()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418608/258228) 
теперь в PHP вы можете обращаться к полям формы `$_POST['items']` как к массиву, к примеру

```
$items = $_POST['items'];
$age5 = $items['age5'];
```

или перебрать их циклом сразу формируя запрос

```
//если не используется  ORM и PDO
$fieldsArray = array();
$valuesArray = array();
foreach($items as $key=>$value){
   // не забудьте экранирование/удаление спецсимволов, html-сущностей и
   // удаление начальных и конечных пробелов из значений полей формы
   array_push($fieldsArray, $key);
   array_push($valuesArray, $value); 
}
$query = 'INSERT INTO tables ('.implode(',',$fieldsArray).') VALUES ('.implode(',',$valuesArray).')';
```