# отправка 2 action в 1 форме

Tags: php, html

```
<form method='get' action='test.php'>
```

можно ли добавить еще 1 action, чтобы значение из формы передавалось на еще одну страницу. Если можно, то как?

Comment: Черз яваскрипт ajax.При form event onsubmit делаете 2 запроса через ajax. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418501/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-%D0%B8-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Нет конечно.имена атрибутов уникальны,то есть не могут повторяться.

Но можно реализовать двумя другими путями:

**Путь првый:**

Поскольку нету метки яваскрипт то приведу первым пример с [php CURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php)
Посылаем запрос на промежуточную страницу `aaa.php` Откуда с помощью CURL запросов можно уже отправлять запросы на другие страницы `bbb.php`,`ccc.php`,...
Или же обработать часть на этой же страниц а остальные послать дальше.Это уже вам решать.

Как отправить запрос с помощью PHP CURL ? Ответов и примеров куча.Первым читайте [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)

**Путь второй:**

Реализовать с помощью Javascript Ajax запросов.Привду шаги исполнния,а примеров также куча։

```
//Jqury
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //.....
    $.ajax({ ... url1 });
    $.ajax({ ... url2 });
    $.ajax({ ... url3 });
    //.....
});
```