# Отменить перезагрузку страницы полсе AJAX-запроса

Tags: php, ajax

Есть обычная форма: `

```
            <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="And your comment" name="posting"> </textarea>


            <button onclick="add_post()" class="button" type="submit" name="send"> Send
            </button>
        </form>`
```

И AJAX:

```
             function add_post() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "post.php",
                    data: {
                        content: $('#textarea').val()
                    }
                });
            }
```

В `post.php` проверяется длинна текста и добавляется в бд.

Вопрос заключается вот в чем: запрос на `post.php` есть, всё добавляется, но страница перезагружается. Как я понимаю, это из-за `type="submit"`.

Если написать вот так:

```
onclick="add_post(); return false"
```

То совсем ничего не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: а почему просто не заменить <button onclick="add_post()" на <a onclick="add_post()"></a> ?

Comment: @Arsen, так тоже пробовала - 302

Comment: Я спинным мозгом чувствую что вы просто не знаете как правильно работать с формой + ajax, посмотрите правильный прмер тут  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418501/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-%D0%B8-javascript

Comment: @Arsen, да, вы правы. Сейчас пытаюсь методом тыка

Comment: Вам правильно сказал user277937, используйте `return: false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

Заменить onclick на id

```
<button id="submit" class="button" type="submit" name="send"> Send</button>
```

Скрипт будет такой:

```
$('#sumit').on('click', function(){
    add_post();
    return false;
});
```

или так:

```
$('#sumit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    add_post();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
<button type="submit" ...
```

на

```
<button type="button" ...
```

чтобы не было автоматической отправки формы и перезагрузки страницы.