# Как сделать ajax обновление контента при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: php, ajax

подскажите есть 2 кнопки

```
 <form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="nazvanie_knopki" value="Нажмите" />
    <input type="submit" name="nazvanie_knopki2" value="Нажмите" />
 </form>
```

и разный контент для сайта на php

```
if( isset( $_POST['nazvanie_knopki'] ) ) { echo '1';} 
elseif ( isset( $_POST['nazvanie_knopki2'] )) {echo '2';}
```

Но при нажатии на кнопки в форме идет перезагрузка страницы . Как сделать без перезагрузки ??

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: preventDefault() использовал? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418501/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-%D0%B8-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мы-то покажем, но будет лучше если ты научишься пользоваться поиском.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
    <body>

      <input class="ajax-form" type="submit" name="nazvanie_knopki" value="Нажмите" />
      <input class="ajax-form" type="submit" name="nazvanie_knopki2" value="Нажмите" />
      <input class="ajax-form" type="submit" name="nazvanie_knopki3" value="Нажмите" />
      <div id="ajax-content">0</div>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".ajax-form").click(function(e) {
        var form = {};
        form[$(this).attr('name')] = 1;
        $.ajax({
          url: '/ajax.php',
          type: "POST",
          data: $.param(form),
          success: function(data) {
          $('#ajax-content').html(data);
          }
        });
          return false;
          // e.preventDefault(); - либо так
      });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Собсна сам `ajax.php`:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['nazvanie_knopki'])) {
    echo '1';
} elseif (isset($_POST['nazvanie_knopki2'])) {
    echo '2';
} else {
    echo '3';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй `e.preventDefault()`

**jQuery**

```
$('form').on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //то, что тебе нужно. Это прерывает стандартное действие браузера
    // ...код
});
```

Comment: Хватит и просто `return false` в данном случае.