# Как запустить JS из PHP без загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Имеется следующая архитектура проекта:

1. `form.php` - формирует страницу с формой, форма работает без
   `submit`, данные передаются через `ajax`.
2. `db.php` - работает с БД, обрабатывает всякую мудреную логику

В файле `db.php` в процессе выполнения логики должны инициализироваться сообщения для пользователя, но без перезагрузки формы `form.php`.

Как это сделать?

Как инициализировать запуск `JS` c `alert`? А еще лучше `bootstrap alert`?
Как передать в этот `JS` значение переменой с текстом сообщения?

Ниже часть кода:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

    require_once("db_connection.php");
    require_once("query_lib.php");

    echo 'TECT ХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХ';

    $docvalues = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['formresult']), true);

    if(isset($docvalues['docclass'])){   // проверяем устанволен ли тип документа (для корректировки)
        $corr_doc_id = $docvalues['fixedItem']['property_fix2'];
        $current_doc_fixed_items = serch_corrected_docs ($corr_doc_id, $connection); // получаем последнюю действующую запись документа
        if ($current_doc_fixed_items == false) {      //если запрос по id документа не нашел документа (или использовался id нового документа, или не найден)
            $message = array('message' => 'ID документа не найден, попробуйте его изменить') ;
            echo json_encode($message);
            return $current_doc_fixed_items;
        }
```

Comment: Вы вызываете db.php из ajax, при этом вы получаете от него результат, который он вернет. Значит вы можете написать js-код в обработчике получения данных от ajax, который по возвращенным данным поймет, что была ошибка и выведет ее подобающим способом. Часто ajax метод возвращает json объект с ответом сервера и например при наличии в нем поля error его содержимое выводят alert или другим удобным способом

Comment: db.php действительно вызывается из ajax,  но как из php в js передать json без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: php не может решать с перезагрузкой страницы или нет. Это решает JS еще при его вызове. И если вы говорите, что вызов идет через ajax, то перезагрузки страницы не будет, если js сам не решит ее перезагрузить после выполнения запроса

Comment: Само использование технологии. ajax  уже говорит о том что страница не будет перезагружаться. Если у вас php как то влияет на перезагрузку страницы, то может у вас там не совсем уж и php

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то когда-то я отвечал на похожий вопрос, самостоятелньый пример здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870600/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-ajax-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83/870621#870621

Comment: @ Manitikyl , ваш вариант я знаю, но: он срабатывает по событию "onclick", у меня такого события нет, есть логика php обработчика, которая решает вызвать или нет JS. Как это сделать?

Comment: @Mike, вы все правильно говорите. Скажите как json передать?

Comment: @ Виталий Шебаниц,  поскольку у меня страница не перезагружается, мне непонятно как запустить JS из php - файла обработчика, который никак не связан со страницей.

Comment: @Sturmer устанавливаете правильный контент: `header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');` (header должен вызываться _до_ вывода клиенту (печати) хоть одного байта данных). В процессе работы скрипта формируете объект, который будет возвращаться `$result = array('error' => 'произошла ошибка');` и когда собираетесь завершаться печатаете `print json_encode($result);`

Comment: И да, JS запускать не надо. js пишется заранее (он уже должен быть на  странице, до вызова ajax). не знаю как вы вызываете ajax, но если например через jquery, то выглядит это как то так: `$.ajax('url', { ..., success: function(result,textStatus,jqXHR) { if(result.error) return alert(result.error); } });` т.е. у вас при вызове ajax метода в любом случае как то задается обработчик успешного выполнения и в нем вы анализируете пришедший ответ и предпринимаете те действия, которые этим ответом диктуются

Comment: Если очень сильно хочется произвольный код, вы всегда можете вернуть его в одном из полей и при его наличии выполнить его. `if(result.jsCode) eval(result.jsCode)`. Но все таки лучше так делать как можно реже. лучше всю обработку написать заранее и передавать только данные. тогда у вас получиться фактически API для общения клиента с сервером и при желании вы легко сможете использовать его для другого клиента. Например сделать мобильное приложение, на java, которое вызывает эту же php, но результат обрабатывает по своему, например выводит этот алерт java средствами в приложении.

Comment: @Sturmer вывести его как результат через echo

Comment: @ ishidex2, echo не получается, т.к. страница уже загружена,  пользователь вводит инфо, инфо обрабатывается в php, а затем результат работы php выводится на странице без ее перезагрузки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Про **AJAX**. Исходя из вашего вопроса и прочитанных комментариев у меня сложилось впечатление, что вы не совсем понимаете, что такое `ajax`. `Ajax` это просто запрос к серверу. Простыми словами вы просто обращаетесь к файлу, например `db.php` тем самым заставляя его выполниться на сервере точно так же, как если бы вы обратились, например через адресную строку. Просто обращаетесь. В зависимости от логики и переданных данных, например через `POST`, ваш скрипт `db.php` может выдавать разные результаты. Соответственно, если в ходе выполнения скрипта есть команда вывода, например `echo`, то и в ответе вы увидите, то что выведет эта команда.
2. Про вашу страницу (**html**). Так как я не смог увидеть ваш супер секретный код  `html` формы (вход,регистрация), то прикладываю небольшой [пример](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/) (**bootstrap**):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="m-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-primary check-login">Submit</div>
</form>
```

3. Далее, чтобы передать на сервер данные введённые в поля формы вешаем событие на `div` с классом `check-login` (наша кнопка). При клике по кнопке собираем данные с полей и отправляем на сервер. Алгоритм, сбор и последующие действия по манипуляции с элементом `form` кладу на ваши плечи. Запрос отправляете на файл `db.php`. Можно всё сложить в переменную и отправить в формате `json` или отправить значение каждого поля отдельно, например по имени поля.
4. Про файл `db.php`. Наверно, ваш `ajax` запрос будет реализован (передавать данные) по методу `POST` и в формате `json`. И если это так, то ваши данные можно вытащить так: `$_POST['auth-data']` (произвольное название, вы использовать своё).  Если вы отправили ваши данные по именам полей ввода, то принять их можно так: `$_POST['email'], $_POST['password']`. Обработку данных опущу. Далее вы формируете ответ. Тут вам надо определиться, какой тип данных вам отправлять? Лучше всего отправлять так же `json`. Формируете массив, например `$request = []`, в котором первый элемент хранит строку с информацией **успех/провал**, второй элемент, так же массив с сообщениями об успехах, и третий с сообщениями о неудачах (провалах). И там где вы выводили данные через `echo`, теперь добавляйте в массив. В конце скрипта конвертируете получившийся массив в `json` `php` [функцией](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) и выводите командой `echo`. ВЫВОД ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ВСЕГО ОДИН РАЗ! Как сказал, [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike), установите заголовок `header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');`.
5. В ответе вы получите строку форма `json`. Декодируйте её в массив. Потом, анализируя (перебирая элементы) можно понять как показать ответ пользователю, и нужно ли показывать его. На странице компонентов есть [подробная инструкция](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/).

Удачи!

Comment: спасибо  за развернутый ответ. Сверхсекретный файл не выложил сюда поскольку он очень большой. У меня все реализовано в точности, как описано у вас, в конце делаю echo json_encode($reuqest).  Вот дальше и возникает вопрос, где искать request? В переменные JS он не попадает, т.к. не выводится на странице, в $_POST то же не попадает.  И как заставить JS вывести его alertom ? Если бы было нажатие на кнопку, например, то  $(".Alert").click(function()? {..}, а тут просто if в php.

Comment: @Sturmer После отправки, посмотрите в инструменте разработчика во вкладке **Network** , что приходит в ответе?

Comment: form.php и куча js файлов - 200,  db.php нет вообще, как будто не исполнялся, но я его исполнение контролировал в phpstorme

Comment: @Sturmer обновите вопрос с кодом `js` и принтскрином.

Comment: принтскрином чего? и каким кодом js? у меня используется 11 js файлов, некоторые на сотни строк (в основном библиотеки) .

Comment: @Sturmer кода делающий запрос. На сервере делали `var_dump()` ожидаемой переменной?

Comment: doox911 , php код сейчас выложу, var_dump не делал, т.к. смотрю все в phpstorm.

Comment: @Sturmer тогда тем более должно быть видно, что и куда уходит и приходит.

Comment: doox911, код выложил

Comment: И что у вас в ответе нету фразы `TECT ХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХ` или информации об ошибке?

Comment: нет я ее не вижу и ошибки тоже. А  может я не там смотрю? Где смотреть лучше? Ведь в браузере она не может быть показана?

Comment: @Sturmer http://imageup.ru/3306932

Comment: Нашел TECT ХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХХ{"message":"ID \u0434\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430 \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d, \u043f\u043e\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0431\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435 \u0435\u0433\u043e \u0438\u0437\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c"}

Comment: @Sturmer У тебя всё работает.  Если мой ответ является решением твоей проблемы прошу его принять.

Comment: подскажи eще как alertoм вывести, плиз. туплю

Comment: @Sturmer в `success` вызываешь открытие окна. В документации `bootstarp` после `html` описания попапа идёт `js` описание. Да и это делается просто `jquery`: `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

Comment: @ doox911, все получилось, просто у меня была проблема alert не работал :).

Answer (score 0):

Итак резюмирую, поскольку я ранее не смог найти в сети понятное объяснение ответа на мой вопрос. Из `JS` вызывается `ajax` выполнение `php` файла:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../php/db.php", // запускаем выполнение php-файла
    data: data_sent_to_php, // передаем в php-файл данные для обработки
    success: function(data){alert(data['message'])}; // выводим ответ php-файла которые он передает в п.2 
});
```

Чтобы `php` файл отправил нам обратно нужные данные необходимо вставить в нем следующий код:

```
$message = array('message' => 'Ваше сообщение') ;    
echo json_encode($message);
```