# Подскажите, есть форма, есть php обработчик , как всё это реализовать без перезагрузки?

Tags: php, ajax

есть форма ,

```html
<form action="#" id="form" method="post">
  <h3>Авто-смарт дисков</h3>
  <p><b>Подключение по SSH(22 порт)</b></p>
  <p>Введите ip сервера :<b>root@</b><input type="text" name="ip"></p>
  <p>Введите пароль : <input type="password" name="pass"></p>
  <p><b>dev/</b><input type="text" placeholder="sda" name="dev"></p>
  <p>
    <input name="grep" type="radio" value="Power_On_Hours"> Power_On_Hours
    <input name="grep" type="radio" value="Total_LBAs_Written"> Total_LBAs_Written
  </p>
  <p>Total_LBAs_Written :
    <select name="byte">
      <option disabled>Выбрать</option>
      <option value="512">512</option>
      <option value="33554432">33554432</option>
    </select>
    <p><b><h4 style="color: red">*В данный момент не все диски доступны для получения информации </h4></b></p>
    <p><b><h4 style="color: red">*Current_Pending_Sector - выводится автоматически. </h4></b></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Запуск"></p>
</form>
```

, хочу реализовать так, что бы к примеру, нажал кнопку, после того как заполнил форму, снизу в div отобразилась инфа, такое возможно? Подскажите пожалуйста, или киньте пример) очень спасете меня)

Comment: Тема - практически дубль этой = https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418501/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-%D0%B8-javascript

Comment: Нет, не тоже самое, я ведь хочу отправить, и получить сразу результат в свой div

Comment: Там в конце ответа есть ссылка, она поможет = https://ru.wh-db.com/article/kak-otpravit-formu-bez-perezagruzki-stranici/

Comment: А я пойму, не зная js?)

Comment: Нет. Для решения заданного вопроса знать JavaScript немножко надо. Но попытаться смысл есть, т.к. там есть примеры, а это упрощает.

Comment: Ну не много то я знаю, буду читать доку, просто думал с примером разберусь, спс)

Comment: А пример всё же можно, более похож на мое?)) у меня всё выводит 1 переменная)