# Передача данных в браузер из Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Я делаю чат на Flask который обменивается сообщениями http запросамм (json rpc, этот пункт менять нельзя). Как только сообщение приходит на мой сервер, я должен вывести его на свою html страницу, без refresh страницы. Как я могу передать данные из flask на веб-страницу не перезагружая ее? Я думал использовать websockets но мне нужно что бы сервер мог обрабатывать http запросы, так что сокеты не вариант

Comment: По http ты не можешь пушить с сервера. Вариант сделать чтобы клиент опрашивал по таймеру бек и подгружал новые данные.

Comment: ajax? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418608/234134